# Unable to drag files after installing communication with python script

Tags: electron

I built an electron app that allowed dragging files in, with a jQuery script that just takes some info from that (path) and adds an li to a list. That's it. It worked great.

Then I followed this guide, because the next step is to send that information to a python script that analyzes the files (maybe relevant: when installing zeroRPC I built from sources, didn't rely on the prebuilt fork that's available there).

Now I get this crazy bug where when I drag files into the app my mouse pointer changes to not-allowed and the drop event doesn't fire. It's so weird.

I don't have any code sample to give because I can't really tell which part is wrong. The only changes I've done are the ones in the guide I linked, and they have nothing to do with the front-end. I'm really confused by this. not-allowed? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as suspected, the issue had nothing to do with either the front end or the back end. None of my code, really. It turned out that since I needed to compile some stuff while preparing zeroRPC, I used powershell as an administrator,, and you [can't drag files from user-run explorer into an admin-run electron app](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5243) - which makes sense and is in fact an expected behavior (it just so happened that I encountered this after doing some work, causing me to think the problem was with something I changed in my code).